# Why the delta at the end of the approximation?

Tags: convolution

The equation to approximate an input signal with a unit impulse in Continuous Time, is shown below, before we take the limit $\hat{x}(t)=\frac{lim}{\Delta\rightarrow0}\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}x(k\Delta)\delta_\Delta(t-k\Delta)\Delta$ <-- why is there a final $\Delta$ multiplying the $\delta_\Delta(t-k\Delta)$?

Comment: try defining formally $\delta_\Delta(t)$. what is the height of that function, given a specific $\Delta$?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean? Is it the discretation process you're after?

Comment: This is to do with the convolution integral and dissertation sounds like it has something to do with representing a CT signal as as series of discrete signals. i think the $\delta_\Delta(t-k\Delta)\Delta$ part does this?

Comment: the height of the function at every $\Delta$ is given by $x(k\Delta)$ for the relevant value of k.

Comment: yes @Princ3Sach, the height of the function, $\hat{x}(t)$ when $k\Delta \le t < (k+1)\Delta$ is $x(k\Delta)$, but the height of $\delta_\Delta(t-k\Delta)$ is $\frac{1}{\Delta}$ because the width is $\Delta$ and the area has to be 1.  so now do you see why you need that factor of $\Delta$ in there?

Answer (score 2):

Here the signal is in continuous time domain. We can approximate any signal with weighted integral of unit impulse. As the signal is in continuous time domain **integration** is used instead of **summation**.

The actual equation is ,
$$x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x(t_0)\delta(t-t_0)dt}$$

In your equation ${lim}_{\Delta\rightarrow0}\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty}$ stands for integration so **$\Delta$** is required at the end, which stands for **dt** in integral.

Hope you clear that.

Comment: GREAT! I think i get it. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_\Delta(t-k\Delta)$ is a spike with value 1. $\Delta$ is the width. It is like you are approximating the area under $x(t)$ with a bunch of rectangles of height $x(k\Delta)$ and width $\Delta$. So area is width by height, hence the multiplication. $x(k\Delta)\delta_\Delta(t-k\Delta)$ is a just a way of writing the discrete set of values at $x(k\Delta)$.